# Windows Event Viewer: Access Denied while trying to view login and logoff events

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, event-viewer

I'm running a localized version of Windows 7. I've followed the following steps to view the dates and times for the login and logoff events carried out on my computer:

- Press WinKey + R.
- Type `eventvwr.msc` and press Enter to launch Event Viewer.
- Click on Windows Logs -> Security

The contents of the middle panel of the application should display the dates and times of the last logons and logoffs, but I get an access denied error.

[image]

Anyone know how to make it go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command as Administrator.

- Press `Win` key
- type `eventvwr.msc` (into search bar)
- right click on found item
- select `Run as administrator`
- enter administrator password

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to do that for the benefit of people who aren't familiar?  Thanks.